# Configuring Twilio softphone to receive calls

Tags: twilio

I have the Twilio browser phone set up and can make calls from my browser. I've read now that you can also receive calls. I can't find where you hook that up and how you actually get alerted that a call is coming in. Can someone help with a walk-thru?

Comment: Dude this question is really out of topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd suggest walking through the Twilio Client for JavaScript quickstarts.  This will show you how to both make calls from your browser and accept inbound calls to your browser.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client

Hope that helps.